# Continuous transmission with USRP B210

Tags: c++, usrp, uhd

I am looking for an SDR solution for continuous transmission of a given IQ record (transmitting the samples in a loop, send first sample again after the last sample was sent). I am wondering if it is possible to implement such continuous transmission via USRP B210 with UHD? Or, can it be monitored how many samples were lost in a way that would include all cases: samples lost within `uhd::tx_streamer::send()` call without fragmentation / `uhd::tx_streamer::send()` call when it handles fragmentation / samples lost between consecutive `uhd::tx_streamer::send()` function calls (when called repeatedly from `while(1)` loop)?

Comment: Why is there no [mre] here?

Answer (score 0):

Sure that works. See [TX samples from file](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/blob/master/host/examples/tx_samples_from_file.cpp) on how to send continous data. For your case you should set `repeat` option and `delay=0` as command line options.